# babel-plugin-react-css-modules adds classes but doesn't transform css

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, react-css-modules

I'm trying to use `babel-plugin-react-css-modules` with an ejected copy of `create-react-app` to scope my LESS CSS.

I've managed to install and configure the plugin and it's setting the scoped classnames properly using the `styleName` property, and I've configured it to work with LESS as well as per the documentation.

However, whilst the generated CSS is imported, it does not transform the classnames to match the classnames set on the elements. Here is the relevant parts of my `webpack.config.dev.js` and `App.js` files.

```
module: {
    // First, run the linter.
    // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
    preLoaders: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            loader: 'eslint',
            include: paths.appSrc,
        }
    ],
    loaders: [
        // ** ADDING/UPDATING LOADERS **
        // The "url" loader handles all assets unless explicitly excluded.
        // The `exclude` list *must* be updated with every change to loader extensions.
        // When adding a new loader, you must add its `test`
        // as a new entry in the `exclude` list for "url" loader.

        // "url" loader embeds assets smaller than specified size as data URLs to avoid requests.
        // Otherwise, it acts like the "file" loader.
        {
            exclude: [
                /\.html$/,
                // We have to write /\.(js|jsx)(\?.*)?$/ rather than just /\.(js|jsx)$/
                // because you might change the hot reloading server from the custom one
                // to Webpack's built-in webpack-dev-server/client?/, which would not
                // get properly excluded by /\.(js|jsx)$/ because of the query string.
                // Webpack 2 fixes this, but for now we include this hack.
                // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1713
                /\.(js|jsx)(\?.*)?$/,
                /\.(css|less)$/,
                /\.json$/,
                /\.svg$/
            ],
            loader: 'url',
            query: {
                limit: 10000,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
            }
        },
        // Process JS with Babel.
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            include: paths.appSrc,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {

                // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                // directory for faster rebuilds.
                cacheDirectory: true,
                plugins: [
                    [
                        'react-css-modules',
                        {
                            //context: paths.appSrc,
                            webpackHotModuleReloading: true,
                            generateScopedName: "[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
                            filetypes: {
                                ".less": "postcss-less"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                ],
            }
        },
        // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
        // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
        // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
        // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
        // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
        {
            test: /\.(css|less)$/,
            loader: 'style?sourceMap!css?importLoaders=1!less?sourceMap!postcss'
        },
        // JSON is not enabled by default in Webpack but both Node and Browserify
        // allow it implicitly so we also enable it.
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json'
        },
        // "file" loader for svg
        {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            loader: 'file',
            query: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
            }
        }
        // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
        // Remember to add the new extension(s) to the "url" loader exclusion list.
    ]
},
```

And my App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../../public/assets/img/logo.svg';
import './App.less';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div styleName="App">
        <div styleName="App-header">
          <img src={logo} styleName="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p styleName="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And from my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "^15.4.2",
"react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "6.7.2",
    "babel-core": "6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "7.1.1",
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^2.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^2.2.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.20.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "1.1.4",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "1.3.0",
    "cross-spawn": "4.0.2",
    "css-loader": "0.26.1",
    "detect-port": "1.1.0",
    "dotenv": "2.0.0",
    "eslint": "3.16.1",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^0.6.2",
    "eslint-loader": "1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.21.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.4.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "0.10.0",
    "fs-extra": "0.30.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.24.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "0.17.3",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.3",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-less": "^0.15.0",
    "postcss-loader": "1.2.2",
    "promise": "7.1.1",
    "react-dev-utils": "^0.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.2"
  },
```

Any ideas on what I've done wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: are you using webpack 1 or 2? can you check what it says in your package.json? if it's webpack 2, I know what's wrong and may be able to provide a helpful answer 

Comment: @PatrickHund It's "webpack": "1.14.0"

Comment: Ok, in wp2, loaders are configured differently, so that is not the issue here

Comment: @ThomasHuxley Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Bob didn't figure it out and abandoned it in favour of styled-components. Your answer looks promising though and I'll see if that works.

Answer (score 5):

Possible answer here, for me what fixed it was making sure my `context` in my webpack config matched my `context` in my babelrc.

webpack.config.js:

```
{
...
context: path.join(__dirname, 'app')
}
```

.babelrc

```
["react-css-modules", {
  "webpackHotModuleReloading": true,
  "context": "./app" // This is important
}],
```